# scriptable FTP client

Tags: scripting, ftp

I need to have a script download all file in a given directory. I only have ftp access.

A quick test shows that I can't talk my ftp client into logging in from the command line. Even after trying Arnshea's answer it refuses to read the password from the file *or* stdin.

Even after logging in I can't download wild cards. (*fixed with `mget`, thanks Arnshea*)

Trying `wget` also fails.

I'd be fine with windows or Linux as long as it's simple.

Comment: What's the problem with wget? Why does it fail?

Comment: wget can't use wildcards

Answer (score 6):

if you're on windows you can pass it a text file with the commands to execute...

e.g.,

```
ftp -s:ftptest.txt ftp.download.com
```

where ftptest.txt contains

```
anonymous
nowhere@noone.net
bin
hash
prompt
mget *.*
quit
```

Comment: Yep, it's hellaciously insecure but heh, security wasn't part of the OP :)  Also, -A can be used in place of the first 2 lines.

Comment: I can't use anonymous and it's not accepting a password from the file

Comment: In the example nowhere@noone.net was the password.  You'll need to change that to whatever the password is.  Same goes for anonymous (change it to your user name).  Don't use -A if you're not using anonymous

Comment: That's what I was trying. As I said FTP won't take the password from the file. When I tried using stdin redirection, it gets to the password prompt and waits for input from the /keyboard/.

Comment: Not sure what's happening on your system.  You sure the password is correct?  Also, make sure the text file is plain text (e.g., use notepad not wordpad).  Works fine for regular and anonymous users on my XP system.

Comment: try it for some non anon login. IIRC the same thing happens on Linux, so whoever wrote ftp thought getting a pw from a file/pipe was a "bad thing" (social engineering and all) and made it not work.

Answer (score 4):

**WinSCP** is [scriptable](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting)

Answer (score 1):

`wget` should work. Try:

`wget ftp://domain.com/full/path --ftp-user=username --ftp-password=password`

Comment: wget had problems with wildcards

Answer (score 1):

Robo-FTP is also [scriptable](http://www.robo-ftp.com/help/3.7/script_commands_grouped_by_function.htm)

Here is a Robo-FTP script to download all the files in a remote folder:

```
WORKINGDIR "c:\destination\folder"
IFERROR GOTO done
FTPLOGON "ftp.mydomain.com" /user="UserID" /pw="secret!"
IFERROR GOTO done
RCVFILE "*" /subdirs /emptydirs
:done
FTPLOGOFF
EXIT
```